# Why does the Google Cloud Function return 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function which does a Stripe Checkout API post call. But everytime the functions is called, in DevTools i see that it returns a "500 Internal Server Error" : {"error":{"message":"INTERNAL","status":"INTERNAL"}}

The code looks likte this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const http = require('http');

// This Cloud Function handles requests from clients and creates a Stripe checkout session for an evening shop.
exports.stripeAvondwinkel = functions.region('europe-west3')
  .runWith({
    memory: '128MB'
  }).https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // Extract the converted list of items from the request data
    const convertedList = data.convertedList;

    // Define constants for the checkout session parameters
    const successUrl = 'https://example.com/succes';
    const mode = 'payment';
    const automaticTaxEnabled = 'true';
    const bezorgkosten = 'XXXXXXXX';

    // Convert the convertedList into line items for the checkout session
    const lineItems = convertedList.map(item => {
      const [prijsID, aantal] = item.split(',');
      return {
        price: prijsID,
        quantity: aantal
      };
    });

    // Construct the form data for the checkout session
    const formData = {
      'success_url': successUrl,
      'mode': mode,
      'automatic_tax[enabled]': automaticTaxEnabled,
      'shipping_options[0][shipping_rate]': bezorgkosten
    };

    // Add line items to the form data
    lineItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      formData[`line_items[${index}][price]`] = item.price.toString();
      formData[`line_items[${index}][quantity]`] = item.quantity;
    });

    // Log the constructed form data
    console.log('Form Data:', formData);

    // Add API post call logic
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const req = http.request({
        hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
        path: '/v1/checkout/sessions',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXX',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }, res => {
        let data = '';
        res.on('data', chunk => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
          // Log the response data
          console.log('Response Data:', data);
          // Resolve or reject the promise based on the response status code
          if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            const url = JSON.parse(data).url;
            resolve(url);
          } else {
            const errorMessage = JSON.parse(data).error.message;
            reject(new Error(`Failed to create checkout session: ${errorMessage}`));
          }
        });
      });

      // Handle request errors
      req.on('error', error => {
        console.error('Request Error:', error);
        reject(new Error(`Request error: ${error}`));
      });

      // Write form data to request body and end the request
      req.write(new URLSearchParams(formData).toString());
      req.end();
    });
  });
```

I attempted to execute the provided code for a Google Cloud Function, expecting it to successfully create a checkout session with the Stripe API based on the provided input data. However, upon execution, I encountered a 500 Internal Server Error. I double-checked the code for any syntax errors or misconfigurations, but couldn't identify the root cause. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrap the code in try catch and see there it fails?